# Out of two google pie chart only one is getting displayed

Tags: javascript, php

Issue with loading two pie charts in a web page.

I am using Laravel frame work and I am trying to display two pie charts in a webpage. but only one pie chart is getting displayed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var analytics = <?php echo $alliance; ?>;
   var analytics2 = <?php echo $partyname; ?>;
   google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
   google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
   function drawChart()
   {    
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(analytics);
    var options = {
     title : 'Percentage of NDA & UPA',
     chartArea:{left:0,top:0,width:"75%",height:"75%"}
    };
    var chart = new 
google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);    
    var data2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(analytics2);
    var options2 = {
     title : 'Percentage by Partywise',
     chartArea:{right:0,top:0,width:"75%",height:"75%"}
    };
    var chart2 = new 
google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div2'));
    chart.draw(data2, options2);
   }
</script>


</head>
 <body>
  @include('includes.topnav')
  @include('includes.bottomnav')  
  <div class="container">
    <h3 align="left">LokSabha Election 2014</h3><br />   
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
          <h3 class="panel-title">Percentage of NDA and UPA</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body" align="left">
         <div id="chart_div" style="width:1800px; height:300px;"> </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body" align="right">
         <div id="chart_div2" style="width:1800px; height:300px;"> </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like bring both pie charts in a single page.

Comment: Typo. You call `chart.draw` two times, change second one to `chart2.draw`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have called chart.draw twice. Please use chart.draw and chart2.draw

> ```
> var chart = new  google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
> chart.draw(data, options);    
> var data2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(analytics2);
> var options2 = {
>  title : 'Percentage by Partywise',
>  chartArea:{right:0,top:0,width:"75%",height:"75%"}
> };
> ```

```
    var chart2 = new 
google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div2'));
    chart2.draw(data2, options2);
   }
```

Comment: Vamsi, Its a very simple mistake, but great catch. Thanks for your help.